# LDAP SQL Extraction - "If" in AD group extract email

Tags: sql, ldap, ldap-query

I have an OU with users within. I want to extract all the emails of those users. I'm using Softerra LDAP explorer. It seems that the extract option doesn't allow to do this "the easy way". So I'm looking at an SQL command to do this.

"cn=xxxx,ou=users,ou=sync,ou=accounts,dc=xx,dc=xxx,dc=net" this is a user. The email is in the "email" field.

The group is here: "CN=group,OU=server,DC=xx,DC=xxx,DC=net",ou=users,ou=sync,ou=accounts,dc=xx,dc=xxx,dc=net"

What command should allow extracting all "email" fields for only users within the group "group" ?

Would be very helpful

Comment: LDAP does not provide a syntax for "JOIN" requests. And I did not found in the `Softerra` SQL documentation something which relate to that. You have to make it a 2 steps searches : 1) Retrieve all the members users DN, 2) Retrieve the emails of all these users.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is the entry

`CN=group,OU=server,DC=xx,DC=xxx,DC=net",ou=users,ou=sync,ou=accounts,dc=xx,dc=xxx,dc=net`

As you suggest by :

> only users within the group "group"

- It is a group with members, and a cross reference (ie. on each user entry you have a kind of `memberOf` attribute which contains the dn of the groups he is in)

  Then you can search all users which match the filter :
  `(memberOf=CN=group,OU=server,DC=xx,DC=xxx,DC=net",ou=users,ou=sync,ou=accounts,dc=xx,dc=xxx,dc=net)` and retrieve the mails attributes

  *If the directory you use does not maintain group membership, you will have to retrieve the users members DN, and make another request to retrieve the mails attributes of all these members*

As you suggest by :

> I have an OU with users within

- It is a branch and all the users you want to retrieve are under this branch

  Then you just have to search all the users under the subtree corresponding to this branch and retrieving the mails attributes.